# Difference between found and find

Tags: tense

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> If you found any activity is missing from the above list, please add.
>
> If you find any activity is missed out from the above list,  please add.

Comment: Why vary from "missing" to "missed out" if you were only concerned about "find" vs "found"?

Answer (score 2):

If you presume they have already looked at the list, use "found".  If you would like them to review the list, but they haven't done so, use "find".

So, since you are putting the sentence below the list, "found" makes sense.

But if you were to put that sentence ABOVE the list, you would need to use "find".

Of course, you could finesse it by saying "If any activity is missing..."

Answer (score 2):

I would not use *found* since no action will have occurred until someone reads the statement.  I would use:

> If you find any activity (that is) **missing** from the above list, please add *it*.

*missed out* generally has a different meaning, as in:

> He **missed out** on a great opportunity.

See [***missed out***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/missed+out)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

"If you find" is more appropriate, as it suggests to the reader to go back and deliberately check.

Comment: As far as *find* vs *found* are concerned, yes, both are correct. As far as the rest is concerned, both are clearly produced by a non-native speaker. A native speaker would never say "please add" in that context and leave it at that. (Please add *what*?)